# How to track current location in android with new architecture components?

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a project, in which I have successfully implemented location tracking feature, and is working perfectly. I am tracking users current location using fused location provider in every 30 seconds.(tracking starts when MainActivity started).

Now I am planning to update that project with newly introduced android architecture components. But I don't know how to implement location tracking with view model.Where is the right place to start location tracking, in **MainActivity or Application** class? Should I use **ViewModel or AndroidViewModel**? How to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way would be to have a `TrackingRepository` where you do all calculations in a background thread of the device location. Create a `MutableLiveData` where you will assign the location. Then update its value using `postValue()` or `setValue()`. Write a public getter for this `MutableLiveData`. This repository will be your location API.

Then your `ViewModel` should call the method of your repository and assign its result to a `LiveData` variable of the `ViewModel`. Then in your Fragment/Activity observe the liveData of your `ViewModel`. Just as the [Guide to App Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html) does.

Remember to use dependency injection which really helps with the new architecture.

Comment: I am confused about, where to ask location permissions and from where to start the service, can you please provide some sample code?

Comment: You need to ask the location permissions in the UI, but access the device location through the repository. About from where to start the service, do not really know. Refer to this post although is not answered yet (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265685/what-is-the-right-place-to-start-a-service-in-mvvm-architecture-android)

Comment: Is there a working example of this setup? It would be great to see a working example ...I plan on doing a test either way.

Comment: But `FusedLocationProviderClient` requires `Context` to be instantiated. How can we provide `Context` to it?

Comment: Use the ApplicationContext instead the Activity Context

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of try, finally I could find the solution.

First create a variable inside the LocationRepository.

```
val currentLocation = MutableLiveData<Location>()
```

Inside the LocationCallBack (onLocationResult)

```
currentLocation.postValue(locationResult.lastLocation)
```

Thereafter in the ViewModel class again

```
val currentLocation = MutableLiveData<Location>()
```

and

```
fun currentLocation(): MutableLiveData<Location>
{
    currentLocation = myLocationProvider.currentLocation
    return currentLocation
}
```

at least you have observe the ViewModel's MutableLiveDate in your Activity/Fragment

```
myLocationProvider.currentLocation.observe(this, Observer { currentLocation ->
            currentLocation?.let {
                //Your code here
            }
})
```

**EDIT**
You have to start the the LocationCallback with suspendCoroutine, GlobalScope and UiDispatcher.

Comment: It's a good practice to encapsulate the MutableLiveData so that the View cannot set a new value.  ```var _currentLocation = MutableLiveData<Location>() ```  this is private to be used in the ViewModel   ```val currentLocation = LiveData<Location>()  get()= _currentLocation```  this is the one to be observed by the View

Comment: @ElizaCamber yes, true. I modified my comment, thanks

Comment: @inspire_coding that's still not what @Eliza said. `currentLocation` should be declared as `private val mCurrentLocation=MutableLiveData<Location>()` (notice the private). And then the exposed (public) value should be immutable (a LiveData, NOT a MutableLiveData) => `val currentLocation: LiveData = mCurrentLocation`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, "private set" variable modifier is native (i.e. "better") way of preventing write access from outside of the class.